# Чтение последней пустой строки файла

Tags: c#, .net, строки, файлы, консоль

Всем привет. Есть метод, который построчно считывает заданный пользователем текстовый файл (с числовыми строками) и передает в другой метод для дальнейшей обработки.

```
private void ReadFile()
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(_filePath))
            {
                string fileLine = "";
                int lineNumber = 0;
                
                while ((fileLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null )
                {
                    lineNumber++;
                    ParseLine(fileLine, lineNumber);
                }
            }
        }
```

Вопрос в пустой строке в файле. Если она не последняя она считывается успешно, но последняя строка не читается. Как можно сделать, чтобы цикл while пропускал последнюю пустую строку ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-Ru/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.endofstream?view=net-6.0

Comment: А что значит - не читается?

Comment: StreamReader вообще не видит, что есть 5я строка в файле. После того как была обработана 4я строка цикл while завершает свою работу.

Comment: А разве вам так не надо?  `чтобы цикл while пропускал последнюю пустую строку ?`

Comment: Нет, 5я строка это, если можно так сказать пустая строка, на которой находится курсор (грубо говоря создана пользователем), т.е. строка существует. В последующей обработке нужно чтобы эта строка была идентифицирована как пустая и попала в соответствующий список пустых ("бракованных") строк (так же как и 3я строка, но с той проблем нет).

Comment: Курсор показывает, куда будет вставлен следующий символ. И если его вставить, то только тогда появится новая строка

Comment: А зачем вообще обрабатывать пустую строку? Какой в этом смысл? Нет данных в строке, нечего и парсить. Суть вопроса поясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете пропускать итерации с пустыми строками.

К примеру:

```
private void ReadFile()
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(_filePath))
    {
         string fileLine = string.Empty;
         int lineNumber = 0;
                
         while ((fileLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null )
         {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileLine))
                continue;

            lineNumber++;
            ParseLine(fileLine, lineNumber);
         }
    }
}
```